# Search in DataTables does not work correctly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bootstrap-4, datatables

I switched from Bootstrap 3.0 to 4.6 and since then the search in a data table does not work correctly anymore.

I use the following scripts (+ the corresponding CSS files):

- bootstrap.bundle.min.js (4.6.2)
- dataTables.bootstrap4.js
- jquery-3.6.0.min.js
- jquery.dataTables.js (1.13.8)
- jquery.dataTables.min.js (1.10.2)

I fill the following table with data from a database (it's not the full code, just the important part):

```
<?php

$fieldlist = '<table id="fieldlist" class="display datatable table table-striped" data-cells="4">
<thead><td>Name</td> <td>Beschreibung wg. Analyse</td> <td>Pflicht?</td>    <td>Format / Bedingung / next / Ziel</td></thead><tbody>';

$fieldlist .= '<tr><td>     
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="fieldname_' . $i . '"     value="' . $field->feld . '"></td> ';
$fieldlist .= '<td> <span hidden>' . $field->feldname2 . '</span> 
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-2"><input style="width:100%;" class="form-control" type="text"   name="feldnameNummer_' . $i . '"    value="' . $field->feldnameNummer . '" ></div>
<div class="col-md-6"><input class="form-control" type="text"   name="fieldname2_' . $i . '"        value="' . utf8_decode($field->feldname2 == 'undefined' ? "" : $field->feldname2) . '"></div> 
</div></td>';

$fieldlist .= '<td><input type="checkbox" name="pflicht_' . $i . '" id="pflicht_' . $field->feld . '" class="toggle" ' . $mandatory . '><label for="pflicht_' . $field->feld . '">&nbsp;  Pflicht</label></td>';

$fieldlist .= '<td><div class="row"><div class="col"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="typ_' . $i . '" id="typ_' . $i . '" disabled readonly value="' . $field->typ . '"></div>';

if ($field->typ == "textfield") {
    $fieldlist .= '<div class="col"><select class="form-control" name="format_' . $i . '"   style="width:100%;">' . $formatoptions . '</select></div></div>';
} elseif ($field->typ == "checkbox") {
    $fieldlist .= '<div class="col"><select class="form-control" name="format_' . $i . '">' .   $checkboxOptions . '</select></div>';
    $fieldlist .= '<div class="col"><select class="form-control" name="prop_' . $i . '">' . $checkboxType .     '</select></div></div>';
} elseif ($field->typ == "buttonfield") {
    $fieldlist .= '<div class="col"><select class="form-control" name="format_' . $i . '">' . $buttonType . '</select></div></div>';
}

$fieldlist .= '</td></tr>';
$i++;

$fieldlist .= '</tbody></table>';
```

The table looks good:

[how the table looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMjGY.png)

If I now, for example, search for "BLZ" (from the 1st row - [example row 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttzvG.png)), then no result is displayed. The search function works for 2nd row and 4th row - [example row 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfhga.png), also not for 3rd row.

The following JavaScript will also be executed:

```
if ($(this).attr('data-cells') == '4' && $(this).attr('id') == 'fieldlist') {
    param = { "aoColumns": [null, null, null, null], "sPaginationType": "full_numbers", "bAutoWidth": false, "bProcessing": true};
} else if ($(this).attr('data-cells') == '4') {
    param = { "aaSorting": [[0, "desc"]], "aoColumns": [{ "sType": "date-eu" }, null, null, null], "sPaginationType": "full_numbers" };
}
```